# localStorage content with time stamp to remove itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I would like to have a timer for content in localStorage.

For example I have got a dynamically updated DIV

```
<div id="news"><p>test</p></div>
```

And managed to add it as html block to localStorage by using this code:

```
$(function() {
   localStorage["homeNews"] = JSON.stringify($("#news").html());
});
$(function() {
   if (localStorage["homeNews"] != null) {
       var contentsOfNews = JSON.parse(localStorage["homeNews"]);    
      $("#news").html(contentsOfNews);
 } 
});
```

I need to add a time stamp to the localStorage["homeNews"] and a snippet which will remove it after 5 minutes by checking the current time and the time stamp of my localStorage.

The fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/Rn4NC/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## LocalStorage Content Timestamp with TTL Time To Live to Remove Itself

> JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Rn4NC/3/

The goal is to provide an interface that is easy to use to pull in data that is not too old based on a time supplied by the programmer.  Here is the simple interface:

### Usage of DB Example with TTL

#### HTML

```
<div id="news"><p>test</p></div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$(function() {
    // Set Value with TTL of 5 Seconds using Milliseconds.
    db.set( "homeNews", $("#news").html(), 5000 );
});

$(function() {
    // Get Value
    var contentsOfNews = db.get("homeNews");

    // Show Value
    $("#news").html(contentsOfNews);
});
```

That's the example usage case, next is the interface definition with TTL support:

#### Local Storage with TTL Interface Definition.

Here is the interface logic for `db` usage and is used in the example above. Checkout the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rn4NC/3/) example for the full usage.

```
$(function(){
    function now () {return+new Date}
    var db = window.db = {
        get  : function(key) {
            var entry = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)||"0");
            if (!entry) return null;
            if (entry.ttl && entry.ttl + entry.now < now()) {
                localStorage.removeItem(key);
                return null;
            }
            return entry.value;
        },
        set : function( key, value, ttl ) {
            localStorage.setItem( key, JSON.stringify({
                ttl   : ttl || 0,
                now   : now(),
                value : value
            }) );
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot PubNub. It looks like a perfect solution to me but I have got a question. If I will browse some where else and come back to this page back after given period (you put 5 sec) will my localStorage get updated or I should be on the page till timer runs out? Sorry if it sounds stupid. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Good question! The answer is that the localStorage will get updated either way even if you navigate away.  You don't need to be on the page until the timer runs out.

Comment: Also if you want **infinite ttl** and never get cleared, you will set the TTL to `0`.  For example:  `db.set( "homeNewsForever", $("#news").html(), 0 );` - will keep the data around forever or until the browser DB is cleared by the user.

Comment: Happy to have made the solution for you!